# Mesh holes filling using advancing front algorithm

Tags: typescript, computational-geometry

I'm trying to implement the hole-filling algorithm described in the following paper: http://www.cad.zju.edu.cn/home/hwlin/pdf_files/A-robust-hole-filling-algorithm-for-triangular-mesh.pdf

So basically I need to construct new triangles from two adjacent edges on a mesh hole. There are three cases:

1. Angle between edges is less than 75 degrees so I have to add one new triangle.
2. Angle between edges is bigger than 75 degrees and less than 135 (2 new triangles).
3. Angle between edges is bigger than 135 degrees (3 new triangles).

Case A is trivial. In case B I tried to calculate the new point as middle point plus bisector divided by Any suggestions on how to calculate new points in case C. Here is the code I wrote:

```
private createNewTriangle() {
    const vi = this.controlPoints[this.minAngleIdx];
    const vi_1 = this.controlPoints[this.minAngleIdx + 1];
    const vi_2 = this.controlPoints[this.minAngleIdx +  2];
    if (this.minAngle <= 75) {
        this.newTriangles.push(vi, vi_1, vi_2);
        this.controlPoints.splice(this.minAngleIdx, 0);
    } else if (this.minAngle > 75 && this.minAngle <= 135) {
        const edge1 = new Vector3().subVectors(vi, vi_1);
        const edge2 = new Vector3().subVectors(vi_2, vi);
        const a = edge1.copy(new Vector3).multiplyScalar(edge2.length());
        const b = edge2.copy(new Vector3).multiplyScalar(edge1.length());
        const bisector = a.add(b).divideScalar(2);
        const newPoint = new Vector3().addVectors(vi_1, bisector);
        this.newTriangles.push(vi, newPoint, vi_1, vi_1, newPoint, vi_2);
    } else {
        // ???
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain how to calculate new points on the advancing front? [rules for creating new points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHp4p.png)

**UPDATE**

For the last case, two new vertices need to be inserted on the trisector. Does anyone know how to compute trisector by given three points?

Comment: Please tag your ptogramming language

Answer (score 1):

Not a great paper is it? First the three rules aren't explained at all, and then θ in example *C* is actually 115°, even though it's meant to be an example with θ>135° (notwithstanding the wonky diagram lines)!

[image]

That said, the this matches the image and could be *the* rule:

- Angle v<sub>new_1</sub>, v<sub>i</sub>, v<sub>new_2</sub> is always 45°.

[image]

However that alone doesn't provide coordinates for v<sub>new_1</sub> and v<sub>new_2</sub>.

**Assuming** the 45° triangle is always orientated to the middle of the angle and line v<sub>new_1</sub>, v<sub>new_2</sub> is perpendicular to the bisector (as in the example), you use the point on the angle bisector line at *shortestSide* units away from v<sub>i</sub> and SOHCAHTOA with an angle of 22.5° for the length of the triangle's sides (dark green hypotenuse), from which you can find the coordinates.
[image]